# I can't install npm packages without getting access denied errors or deprecated. I tried using sudo and audit fix. wha t else should I try?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

npm install -g yo  errno: -13,   syscall: 'open',   code: 'EACCES',   path: '/Users/[myname]/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.2830150675' }

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a permissions issue.
But since you've already tried "sudo" the solution might be elsewhere.

This could be a symbolic linking (symlink) issue - Windows uses a different filesystem and permissions structure compared to Linux - and npm just fails to work around these things automatically.

This might help -

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

You will have to add **--no-bin-links** to all your npm install/update/remove commands to work around this issue.